# Flask login cookie sets path

Tags: python, flask

I am using flask login to login via an API endpoint. The endpoint in question is

```
/auth/login
```

Once I have successfully logged in and I hit this path which is another endpoint I have created I get a not logged in error.

```
/company/addusertocompany
```

Upon further inspection I can see the session being set is like so:

```
session=.eJwljg; Path=/auth; HttpOnly;
```

As you can see it is limiting the session to path /auth and therefore no other endpoints work when I require the user to be logged in. This is from Postman but I presume it does the same on a web browser. Has anyone ran into the same issue and if so how did you get around it?

If anyone needs to see the code I can post it too but it is rather large and I didn't want to spam this question with anything that isn't required.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is wondering on what causes this problem it is

```
app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT'] = './'
```

should be

```
app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT'] = '/'
```

The dot in the config sets it to the current path which of course makes sense but in the context of having your application inside a subfolder like so where your run.py calls app.py in an application factory design pattern you should use "/" to allow the full domain access.

```
-models.py
-app.py
run.py
```

More information on this can be found at https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#cookie-settings - Unfortunately there is no real examples on here but the above applies.